# What object same as Signature (java.security.signature) on Python?

Tags: java, python, python-2.7, m2crypto, ecdsa

I want to verify ECDSA signature generate on android by using python.

But I can't found object or any thing same as Signature object in Python.

Here is my verify code if using Java

```
String origin = txtOrigin.getText().toString();
try {
    sig = Signature.getInstance("NONEwithECDSA","SC");
    sig.initVerify(publicKey);
    byte[] stringInput = origin.getBytes("UTF-8");
    sig.update(stringInput);
    txtVerify.setText(sig.verify(signatureBytes)+"");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I think you are interested in https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto/blob/master/M2Crypto/EC.py

Comment: Thanks for your help, let me check